# Unknown error for response Wcf Rest -Get C#

Tags: c#, wcf, soapui

I have a WCF rest get service to get all the packs from database:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPackages
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    List<WsPackage> GetAllPackages();
}
```

*** This is my class  WsPackage:

```
 [DataContract]
public class WsPackage : WsEntities
{
    [DataMember]
    public string EntryPeriod { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Phase { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int? EntryPeriodId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int? PhaseId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public packStatus Status { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public object EffectiveLockOrProtect { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public packLock EffectiveLockOrProtectLocal { get; }
}
```

the implementation of this service is well working ,and if I make a breakpoint ,I get the correct result:

[image]

- But if I let the breakpoints, I got an infinite loop, despite I have no conditions or anything to infinity, all the code is ok !

*And this is the excption from WCF traceLog:

```
    <TraceData>
        <DataItem>
            <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
                <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.ServiceOperationExceptionOnReply.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
                <Description>Replying to an operation threw a exception.</Description>
                <AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132156151017014560</AppDomain>
                <Source>System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime/44304485</Source>
                <Exception>
                    <ExceptionType>System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException, System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
                    <Message>No set method for property 'EffectiveLockOrProtectLocal' in type 'SysLap.Services.Library.DataExtractor.Entity.Pack.WsPackage'.</Message>
                    <StackTrace>   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.ThrowInvalidDataContractException(String message, Type type)
   at WriteWsPackageToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at WriteArrayOfWsPackageToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, Object graph)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterMessageFormatter.SingleParameterBodyWriter.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriterMessage.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageWriter.WriteMessage(Message message, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 initialOffset, Int32 maxSizeQuota)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WebMessageEncoderFactory.WebMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.SerializeBufferedMessage(Message message, Boolean shouldRecycleBuffer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.SendReplyCore(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.SendReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestContext.OnReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpContext.OnReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextBase.Reply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.Reply(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)</StackTrace>
                        <ExceptionString>System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: No set method for property 'EffectiveLockOrProtectLocal' in type 'SysLap.Services.Library.DataExtractor.Entity.Pack.WsPackage'.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.ThrowInvalidDataContractException(String message, Type type)
   at WriteWsPackageToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at WriteArrayOfWsPackageToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, Object graph)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterMessageFormatter.SingleParameterBodyWriter.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriterMessage.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageWriter.WriteMessage(Message message, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 initialOffset, Int32 maxSizeQuota)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WebMessageEncoderFactory.WebMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.SerializeBufferedMessage(Message message, Boolean shouldRecycleBuffer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.SendReplyCore(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.SendReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestContext.OnReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpContext.OnReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextBase.Reply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.Reply(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)</ExceptionString>
                </Exception>
            </TraceRecord>
        </DataItem>
    </TraceData>
```

- First,I try adding private set on the property EffectiveLockOrProtectLocal:

  [DataMember]
      public packLock EffectiveLockOrProtectLocal { get; private set; }

But always I have the same error.

- Then I try modify my class WsPackage ( I comment the property EffectiveLockOrProtectLocal  and I make IgnoreDataMember for the property EffectiveLockOrProtect :

  ```
       [IgnoreDataMember]
  public object EffectiveLockOrProtect { get; set; }
     //[DataMember]
  //public packLock EffectiveLockOrProtectLocal { get; }
  ```

  With this modificaton, I have the good response : 84 values.

So how can I fix this problem to work with the two properties : EffectiveLockOrProtect  and EffectiveLockOrProtectLocal ?

Comment: Looks like cirular references, but you're missing all relevant details from your question. Show relevant code, but especially turn on WCF tracing and obtain the actual exception.

Comment: @CodeCaster, in fact I haven't any WCF tracing , this is my problem,just "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset", 
so what can I do ? Thanks,

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look and do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution, first I must add the set to the property EffectiveLockOrProtectLocal:

```
 [DataMember]        
    public packLock EffectiveLockOrProtectLocal { get; set; }
```

And I add the IgnoreDataMemberAttribute to the EffectiveLockOrProtect property :

```
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public object EffectiveLockOrProtect { get; set; }
```

Comment: Omitting the property is helpful for your issue. I think we just add setter to the property that will solve the issue.

Comment: yes I am agree with you, and we can add setter : private , protected or internal

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with the serialization and deserialization.
Do your server-side and client-side share data contracts? Otherwise, serialization problems are inevitable when using the ORM framework to return data. By default, DataContract is the default serialization setting. So please keep the data contracts consistent on the client-side and the server-side.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: thanks for your replay @Abraham Qian, i, fact you are right it is problem of serialization, and looking at the link, I test the IgnoreDataMember for a property and the other property I comment it, and I have the good response , it is Ok, but how can I fix it then ?
I modified my question with this all details.